# Can you login an agent with Asterisk ARI

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

I'm trying to build an agent app that can have agent controls (login, logout, pause...etc). I now see that Asterisk 13 has an ARI. What I would like to know is how I can send agent commands using the ARI, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do Originate action.

In created call you can do any asterisk app, including AgentLogin

Answer (score 0):

You mean agent controls like Agent Login, Logout, Pause, etc?
Then Asterisk ARI don't!

Asterisk ARI is introduced to get a full call control in a single point. You can build applications with it. There are no rules or app/business logic predefined.

In your case, the agent controls are web or desktop dependent which has nothing to do with ARI.